# Storing videos in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'am doing academic project a website that would let students upload and download files.

Would it be better to insert text files photos and videos directly into database or store them onto a server and have a link to them in database?

Can you discuss the PERFORMANCE and other issues in doing it either ways.
Note: I'am using MySQL database and I would also want to upload videos that are very lengthy (like an hour) and may have a file size of 1 GB, too.

Comment: Basically, let filesystems handle what they do best (storing files), and databases handle what they do best.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store video at some folder and path to that video with unique name needs to store into the database.

All the media files has to be stored at some location and have to store link of it in database.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out yourself already there are 2 possible ways to do this:

1. Storing the whole file (metadata you need + the videos themselves) in a database
2. Storing just links to the files in the database (so the metadata you need) while the videos themselves are stored on the hard drive (or another hard drive)

The 2nd method is generally prefered (despite indexes helping out with pure performance), because:

- When you backup the database it is down for a WAY longer time if you also have the video data in it.
- SQL queries that also give back the video data take WAY longer (index or not) because they just need to return way more data. This also leads to the database server having to work way more.
- In cases of many deletes and inserts,... you fill your transaction log quite rapidly and it gets quite large.

Additionally: The file system is usually quite good at managing files (regardless of the operating system running) as it is made just for that.

So in essence and to round it up: It is not necessary to store the files themselves in the database and does not bring any advantages. Even more so backup/restore operations for the database take way longer and you fill the logs faster thus you need more space on the database server. In addition to this sql commands for the 1st variant that are not built accordingly take way longer (although inserts and deletes will ALWAYS take longer, thus I'm speaking there only about selects that can be made to be quite fast still).

One downside to the 2. variant though: You need 2 backup methods. 1 for the database and a second one for the files themselves. A second possible one is that you would need to store/delete the files manually and need appropriate routines for that.